# Eclipse - search in the list of members for Content Assist?

Tags: eclipse, search, member, content-assist

How to find a specific method in the list of members of the class.
Which opens after pressing **Ctr+Space** with Content Assist in Eclipse.

For example, a members list of class `File`:

```
load
close
read
readLine
write
writeLine
```

If the open list then type the word `"Line"`:
MS VS - showing only the methods (`readLine` and `writeLine`).
Eclipse - will close the list of members. Since looking for entering the beginning of the word.

Can the Eclispe just do a search in the list of members as MS VS?

Answer (score 0):

Enter "line" instead of "Line" or disable *Camel case matching* in the [Java Content Assist preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-content-assist.htm).

Eclipse allows power users to shorten searches by taking upper case characters as sub-word start characters, e.g. searching for `NPE` will directly show you "NullPointerException". You probably trigger that search and it does no longer search for other sub word matches.

Comment: case does not matter.
as soon as I try to enter the substring to search for. the window is closed!